# How can I get user's email address using Google+ API in Zend Framework1?

Tags: zend-framework, google-api, google-plus, google-oauth, google-authentication

I have integrated the Google API in my example to log in my website through Google+ for fetching the details of users email, first name and lastname from his/her profile. When i use the below function

```
    public function getProfile()
   {
    $endpoint = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo';
    return (array) json_decode($this->_getData('profile', $endpoint));
   }
```

I am getting the output as

```
    Array ( [firstname] => xxxx [appid] => 11XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX92 [email] => [lastname] => YYYY [location] => [username] => XXXX YYYY )
```

Where as the `email` is empty.

How to get the email id? What uri must be written in `$endpoint` here to get the email id along with the other data?

Answer (score 2):

You don't show what scopes you are requesting, but it seems likely that you are not asking for the *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email* scope.

However, **the userinfo scopes and endpoints have been deprecated and will be removed in September 2014**.

Going forward, you should use the *email* scope with one of the profile scopes (such as *profile*, *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me*, or *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login*) to get access to the user's email, and then use one of the Google+ API endpoints such as [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) with a userid of "me".

Answer (score 0):

@prisoner is spot on, if you request the `email` scope, you will be able to get the user's email address in `plus.people.get` API calls. I'll show you how to do this in JavaScript:

Add the Google APIs with the following code before your closing body tag, it's ugly, but a standard for loading external libraries asynchronously:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script');
    po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://plus.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Add the signin button:

```
<button class="g-signin"
    data-scope="email"
    data-clientId="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
    data-callback="onSignInCallback"
    data-theme="dark"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin">
</button>
```

Handle the signin response:

```
function onSignInCallback(){
```

...

Load the Google+ API client and handle the auth response:

```
  gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function(){
    if (authResult['access_token']) {
      gapi.client.plus.people.get({'userId':'me'}).execute(
        function(resp){
          alert(resp.emails[0].value)
        });          
    } else if (authResult['error']) {
      // There was an error, which means the user is not signed in.
      // As an example, you can handle by writing to the console:
      console.log('There was an error: ' + authResult['error']);
    }
    console.log('authResult', authResult);
  });
}
```

[Demo is available here.](http://wheresgus.com/emaildemo.html)